# How to fix "This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, csv, groupdocs

I'm facing this error while attempting to convert a CSV file to HTML using GroupDocs. The code for converting csv to html I copied from groupdocs documentation.can somebody help me out.

**Bellow is the code**

```
let filePath = 'sampel/csvFile.csv'
let filecontent = `Name,Age,Email,Address
John Doe,30,john.doe@example.com,123 Main St
Jane Smith,25,jane.smith@example.com,456 Elm Ave
Michael Johnson,28,michael.johnson@example.com,789 Oak Rd
Emily Williams,32,emily.williams@example.com,101 Pine Lane`;

let fileApi = conversion_cloud.FileApi.fromKeys(clientId, clientSecret);

let uploaRequest = new conversion_cloud.UploadFileRequest(filePath,filecontent);


await fileApi.uploadFile(uploaRequest).then(async (result, err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("upload- ", err);
    return res.status(500).send(false);
  } else {
    console.log(" document uploaded", result);
  }
  let loadOptions = new conversion_cloud.CsvLoadOptions();
  loadOptions.separator = ",";
  loadOptions.convertDateTimeData = true;

  
 convertOptions = new conversion_cloud.HtmlConvertOptions();
 convertOptions.fixedLayout = false;
 convertOptions.usePdf = false;

  let settings = new conversion_cloud.ConvertSettings();
  settings.filePath = filePath;
  settings.format = "html";
  settings.loadOptions = loadOptions;
  settings.convertOptions = convertOptions;
 

  result = await convertApi.convertDocument(
    new conversion_cloud.ConvertDocumentRequest(settings)
  );
  console.log("CSV file converted to HTML successfully.");
  // console.log('Output HTML file:', outputFile);
  return res.send({
    data: result.toString(),
  });
});
```

**Bellow is the error that I m getting In coverted HTML**

```
<p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
```

Comment: This question is about [`java`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) or [`javascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)?

Comment: about javaScript

Comment: So you must change the tag `java` to `javascript`